# Set "start in" box for a shortcut C#

Tags: c#, shortcut

How can I set the start in path for a shortcut? I am creating the shortcut using

```
WshShellClass WshShell = new WshShellClass(); 
IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe to set that you use the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae0a4aee%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property of `IWshShortcut`

```
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\temp";
```

[See this link for a C# tutorial on creating shortcuts](http://zayko.net/post/How-to-create-Windows-shortcut-%28C%29.aspx)